# Magento2 constructors with scalar values

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

What would be the correct way to instantiate such a class in magento 2?

```
class MyClass
{
    private $myStringVale;
    private $myIntValue;

    public function __construct($myStringVale, $myIntValue)
    {
        $this->myStringVale = $myStringVale;
        $this->myIntValue = $myIntValue;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {

    }

}
```

The 2 values will be taken from query parameters in the current request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that handles the instantiation of your class (probably a controller) should have as dependency an instance of `MyClassFactory` (that will be autogenerated). That will actually create the instance of `MyClass`.

```
protected $myClassFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...
    MyClassFactory $myClassFactory,
    ...
) {
    ....
    $this->myClassFactory = $myClassFactory;
    ...
}
```

This way you can have in any method of your controller (or whatever) this

```
$stringValue = $this->getRequest()->getParam('something');
$intValue = $this->getRequest()->getParam('something_else');  
$data = [
   'myStringVale' => $stringValue,
   'myIntValue' => $intValue 
];
$myClassInstance = $this->myClassFactory->create($data);
```

The keys of the `data` array should be named as the constructor parameters.